# Can I get RabbitMQ to have a unique constraint on tasks?

Tags: rabbitmq

If my consumers are slow, my publisher may republish the same task. Is it possible to configure RabbitMQ to only maintain uniqueness of my tasks in queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ doesn't look in message body, and it looks like that with headers and arguments your problem can't be solved. You should take care about dups on client side.

P.S.: anyway, every consumer should take care about dups, the reasons is

> There is a possibility of message duplication here, because the broker
>   might have sent a confirmation that never reached the producer (due to
>   network failures, etc). Therefore consumer applications will need to
>   perform deduplication or handle incoming messages in an idempotent
>   manner.

from [official docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html#producer)

Comment: That reason wouldn't apply to my use case. I just want my publisher to push jobs onto a queue and have the queue drop ones it already have. But fair enough, I will maintain state on my db on what has been scheduled.